# Ошибка с массивом error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции

Ошибку ловлю на строке 'int *mass1=  ArrayGenerate(raz);':

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int ArrayGenerate(int raz) {
    int* mass1 = new int[raz];
    for (int i = 0; i < raz; i++) {
        mass1[i] = rand() % 200 - 100;
        cout << mass1[i] << " ";
    }
    return *mass1;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    int raz, n, k;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Ввести длинну массива \n";
    cin >> raz;
    int* mass1 = ArrayGenerate(raz);

    cout << "\n Введите номер элемента, с которого хотите начать удаление: ";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "\n Введите количество элементов, которые хотите удалить:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = k; i < raz - n; i++) {
        mass1[i] = mass1[i + n];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < raz - n; i++)
        cout << mass1[i] << ' ';
    system("pause >> void");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках лучше при цитировании оформлять как "код" . Иначе они могут быть искажены средствами форматирования SO до бессмысленного состояния. В вашем случае именно это и произошло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип возвращаемого значения должен быть указатель на массив , вот как правильно:

```
int *  ArrayGenerate(int raz);
{
int *mass1 = new int[raz];
for (int i = 0; i < raz; i++)
{
mass1[i] = rand() % 200 - 100;
cout << mass1[i] << " ";
}
return mass1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Ну ведь все ясно говорит компилятор. Ваша функция `ArrayGenerate` возвращает `int`, а присваивать вы пытаетесь переменной типа `int*`.

Явная ошибка в `ArrayGenerate` - вы возвращаете не созданный массив, а значение его первого элемента (получая тем самым утечку памяти).

Объявите ее как возвращающую `int*`, а в ней напишите

```
return mass1;
```

И, кстати, в конце программы неплохо бы освободить память, вызвав

```
delete[] mass1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Массив интов пытаетесь передать как инт. Исправьте инт на инт* в возвращаемом типе и не разыменовывайте